# Error Handler vs. Unknown Endpoints in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, backend

I currently have the code below in an backend server built with express. Looking at this code, I would have expected the call to `next(error)` on line 11 to first hit the `app.use(unknownEndpoint)` middleware, resulting in a message of `{ error: "unknown endpoint" }` to the client.

However, it does actually execute the code in the error handler. I think something in my understanding of Express if off, but I'm not sure what.

As far as I understood, all middleware are executed in order. So wouldn't that mean that `unknownEndpoint` would be executed every time there's an error before we could even get to the error handler?

```js
app.get("/api/notes/:id", (request, response) => {
  Note.findById(request.params.id)
    .then((note) => {
      if (note) {
        response.json(note);
      } else {
        response.status(404).end();
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      next(error);
    });
});


const unknownEndpoint = (request, response) => {
  response.status(404).send({ error: "unknown endpoint" });
};

app.use(unknownEndpoint);

const errorHandler = (error, request, response, next) => {
  console.error(error.message);

  if (error.name === "CastError") {
    return response.status(400).send({ error: "malformated id" });
  }

  next(error);
};

app.use(errorHandler);
```

Answer (score 2):

Express is able to differentiate regular middlewares from error middlewares by checking their arity (meaning the number of arguments).

It appears as a detail of this paragraph in the documentation:
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers

> Define error-handling middleware functions in the same way as other middleware functions, except **error-handling functions have four arguments instead of three**: (err, req, res, next).

So, if you call `next(err)`, Express looks for a middleware with 4 arguments to execute in its internal middlewares list.

Comment: Hmm, I see — so you're saying if I pass an argument into `next(arg)` it will skip all middleware with three arguments?

Comment: Yes, if you want a middleware to propagate a success, you don't pass anything to the `next()` call.